# "fake" duplicate on SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a problem that is driving me crazy :

My SQL results are displaying "fake" data :

Here is my tables : 
[SQL SERVER TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BUC0.png)

```
    select DISTINCT NumeroSerie, tp.Temps, pe.Duree from 
VoilierInscrit vi 
join Course co on vi.idCourse = co.Id_Course
join Epreuve ep on co.Id_Course = ep.idcourse
join Penalite pe on ep.Id_Epreuve = pe.idepreuve
join Tps tp on ep.Id_Epreuve = tp.IDepreuve
where tp.IDvoilierInscrit = vi.Id_VoilierInscrit
and pe.VoilierInscrit = vi.Id_VoilierInscrit 
OR tp.IDvoilierInscrit = vi.Id_VoilierInscrit
ORDER BY Temps
```

Here is the result of that query :

```
NumeroSerie       Tps          Duree
   KB48         00:05:00     00:05:00
   JY90         00:15:00     00:05:00
```

Problem is only "JY90" should have a "Duree", KB48 is not linked to "penalite", i know how to display only JY90 but i need both of them.

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: Your JOIN to Penalite is ON `ep.Id_Epreuve = pe.idepreuve`. Based on your diagram, perhaps you should JOIN ON `vi.id_penalite = pe.idpenalite`.

Comment: @Serge Thanks for your reply, but in that way, it only shows me JK90, but now KB48 is not displayed as it doesn't have a "penalite"

Comment: If you want a NULL value to be displayed for KB48, then replace `JOIN Penalite` with `LEFT JOIN Penalite`.

Comment: @Serge Thanks a lot serge ! It works now ! Have a good day dude !